# Django updateView saving another instance instead of updating

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

im trying to update my model but it just creates another instance and i cant figure out why. i was under the impression that all i needed was:

```
class QuestionUpdate(generic.UpdateView):
    model = models.Question
    form_class = QuestionForm
```

and it would take care of it for me but that doesnt seem to be the case.
im in django 1.11 and running python 3.6. Any and all help is appreciated.

**models.py**

```
class Question(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date_updated']
    # user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="question", default='')
    question = models.TextField(unique=False, blank=False, null=False)
    question_html = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False)
    answer = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False)
    answer_html = models.TextField(blank=False,null=False)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question
        # ^ to display an object in the Django admin site and
        # as the value inserted into a template when it displays an object.

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.question_html = misaka.html(self.question)
        self.answer_html = misaka.html(self.answer)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**views.py**

```
class QuestionUpdate(generic.UpdateView):
    model = models.Question
    form_class = QuestionForm
    # fields = ('question', 'answer')

    def edit_question(self, request, id):
        question = get_object_or_404(Question, id=id)
        form = QuestionForm(request.POST, instance=question)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
```

**forms.py**

```
class QuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):
# your_name = forms.CharField(label='Your name', max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        fields = ("question", 'answer')
        model = models.Question
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'questionupdate/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.QuestionUpdate.as_view(), name='update'),
```

Comment: First, please fix your indentation, and post your URLs. What is the point of that `edit_question` method? It won't be called by anything.

Comment: @DanielRoseman - indentation fixed. apologies, i thought stack would pick it up from copy/paste. Now that you point it out, it doesnt make sense for it to be in views.py. i imagine it should be somewhere in  models....or just not be used. i don't know how to call defs yet...still trying to figure that out.