# Why is my Update URL link kicking me to the CreateNew html view

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

so this is a tag on from my previous stackoverflow post:

[Django updateView saving another instance instead of updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49341267/django-updateview-saving-another-instance-instead-of-updating?noredirect=1#comment85682686_49341267)

and i think i've narrowed it down. Whats happening is that when i click on the link to update my view, it sends me to the "create new" page. my problem is that I cant figure out why its doing that.

Any and all help is appreciated.

here is the code:

**question_form.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load bootstrap3 %}
{% block content %}
<h4>Create New Question</h4>
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'questions:create' %}" id="questionForm">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% bootstrap_form form %}
    <input type="submit" value="Post" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

**question_update.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load bootstrap3 %}
{% block content %}

<h4>Update Question</h4>
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'questions:update' pk=question.pk %}" id="questionForm">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% bootstrap_form form %}
    <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

**question_detail.html**

```
{% block content %}
    this is the question detail view
<h3>{{ question.question_html|safe }}</h3>
<h3>{{ question.answer_html|safe }}</h3>
<a href="{% url 'questions:update' pk=question.pk %}"> Update Question</a>
{% endblock %}
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'new/$', views.CreateQuestion.as_view(), name='create'),
url(r'questionupdate/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.QuestionUpdate.as_view(), name='update'),
url(r'questiondetail/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.QuestionDetail.as_view(), name='single'),
```

**views.py**

```
class CreateQuestion(generic.CreateView):
    model = models.Question
    form = QuestionForm
    fields = ('question', 'answer')
    success_url = reverse_lazy('questions:all')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.user = self.request.user
        self.object.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)

class QuestionDetail(generic.DetailView):
    model = models.Question

class QuestionUpdate(generic.UpdateView):
    model = models.Question
    form_class = QuestionForm
    context_object_name = 'question'
```

Answer (score 0):

From your `urls.py` the name of update view is only `update`. You can try only update tag in html file Like

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load bootstrap3 %}
{% block content %}

<h4>Update Question</h4>
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'update' pk=question.pk %}" id="questionForm">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% bootstrap_form form %}
    <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: please update question_detail.html also. And let me know

Comment: I should have clarified that these html files being shown are within another app. i've set my root urls.py to INCLUDE this apps urls.py. thus the need for the "questions:" part of the link.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out. it turns out I was missing the template name part under my Create and update views which directs them to their own html templates:

```
class CreateQuestion(generic.CreateView):
    model = models.Question
    form_class = QuestionForm
    fields = ('question', 'answer')
    template_name = "questions/question_form_create.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy('questions:all')

class QuestionUpdate(generic.UpdateView):
    model = models.Question
    form_class = QuestionForm
    template_name = "questions/question_form_update.html"
```